# $W$ is an irreducible $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $G=\langle r,s|r^3=s^2=e,sr=r^{-1}s\rangle$ the dihedral group and

$W=_{\mathbb{C}[G]}\langle e+\omega^2r+\omega r^2, s+\omega^2rs+\omega r^2s\rangle$ a submodule of the regular module $\mathbb{C}[G]$ where $\omega$ is a primitive root of order 3.

I want to prove that $W$ is an irreducible $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module.

I know that $V=\mathbb{C}^2=\langle e_1,e_2\rangle$ with

$e_1\cdot r= \omega e_1$, $e_1\cdot s=e_2$ is an irreducible $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module.

I consider $f:V\rightarrow W$, $f(e_1)=e+\omega^2r+\omega r^2$. This is a morphism of $\mathbb{C}[G]$-modules.

$f$ is surjective

$V$ is an irreducible $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module$\Rightarrow$ $f$ is injective $\Rightarrow $ $f$ is an isomorphism$\Rightarrow$ $W$ is an irreducible $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module

It is right? There exists a shorter proof?

Comment: I believe you mean 'isomorphism' instead of 'automorphism'. Also note that $f$ being injective already follows from its surjectivity and the equality of dimensions of $W$ and $V$.

Comment: If you are familiar with character theory, calculating character $\chi$ of $W$ and  show $\langle \chi, \chi \rangle_G = 1$ is another way to solve your problem.

Comment: This is correct, yes.

Comment: @Orat How can I deduce the representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is right.

---

Here is another solution using character theory of finite groups. Set
$$ w_1 := e + \omega^2 r + \omega r^2, \quad w_2 := s + \omega^2 rs + \omega r^2s.$$
You already had a $\mathbb{C}$-basis $\{ w_1, w_2 \}$ of $W$ and noticed that the action of $G$ to $w_1$ as
$$ w_1 r = \omega w_1, \quad w_1 s = w_2.$$
So it remains to calculate the action of $G$ to $w_2$ and we can get
$$ w_2r = \omega^2 w_2, \quad w_2s = w_1.$$
In other words, what we've got so far is
$$ [w_1, w_2]r = [w_1, w_2] \begin{bmatrix}\omega & 0 \\ 0 & \omega^2\end{bmatrix},
\quad
[w_1, w_2]s = [w_1, w_2] \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
and hence the character $\chi$ of $W$ is given by
$$ \chi(1) = 2, \quad \chi(r) = -1, \quad \chi(s) = 0.$$
Now it is clear that $\langle \chi, \chi \rangle_G = 1$ and we can conclude that $W$ is an irreducible $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module.

Comment: Very easy! Thank you!